# If I buy OSX Lion, will I be able to upgrade to OSX Mountain Lion for free?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently using an iMac from 2009 running OSX Leopard 10.6.8.

I need this machine to develop iOS applications, and to do that I need xCode 4, and to use xCode 4 I need to have OSX Lion installed.

However I just read that OSX Mountain Lion is just around the corner, possibly coming out this end of the month. If I buy Lion for 30$, will I get Mountain Lion (valued at 20$ in app store) for free?

Comment: It seems most likely that Mountain Lion will be released on 25 July. Can you wait five days?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is just valid if you bought a new Mac machine between June 11, 2012 and the date when Mountain Lion is available in the App Store, according to [this page](http://www.apple.com/osx/uptodate/).

Answer (score 0):

if you sign into your developer account with apple, you will also see a download link for xcode 4.2 for snow leopard.